# Conflict between .NET Maui permissions and sqlite-net-pcl?

Tags: .net, maui, permission-denied, sqlite-net

I am an amateur, trying to write an app that uses a sqlite database. I want the app to have read/write access to the Documents folder on my Android phone. However, I am having trouble with read/write permissions.

I created a very simple app, based on the Visual Studio .NET Maui template. I set READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as required permissions in the Android manifest, and I sought permissions using Permissions.RequestAsyc<Permissions.StorageWrite>. Running it on an Android 14.0 emulator, that gave me write access to the Documents folder - I could use File.Copy() to copy a file to it.

I then installed sqlite-net-pcl, using the NuGet Package Manager, and did nothing else. I could no longer write to the Documents folder, and the App info on the emulator told me that I had permission to access "Music and audio and Photos and videos" (but not other files).

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the sqlite-net-pcl package and test it again? Will it still can not  get the file?

Comment: Yes, access to Documents returns if I uninstall the sqlite-net-pcl package, and it goes again if I reinstall it.  I get the same with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.

Comment: This is the third party NuGet package. You can ask the developer about this issue on the GitHub and follow it up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.